# volley _ jsonArrayRequest with POST method

Tags: java, php, android, sql-server, android-volley

Using android studio I'm trying to get a JsonArray with JsonArrayRequest and Post method, but it didn't work (the POST method send an empty string)so I used a StringRequest instead, but still, there is no response! when I run the program nothing change.

I want to send a specific email to the database and return the name and investment type for all the people who follow this email.

This project is only for testing so I didn't use a listView, and I have Internet permission and have added the volley library.

**My Main Activity:**

```
    final TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t1);
    final TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t2);

    final RequestQueue followsQuery =  Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest( Request.Method.POST, "http://...", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            try {

                JSONArray array=new JSONArray(response);

                int i =0;

                while (i<array.length()){

                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    t1.setText(object.getString("Name"));
                    t2.setText(object.getString("Investment Type"));

                    i++;
                }

            } catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> p = new HashMap<String, String>();
            p.put("email", "Raghad1@gmail.com");
            return p;
        }
    };
    followsQuery.add(request);
}
}
```

**the PHP file:**

```
<?php

require 'connection.php';

$email =  $_POST['email'];
//echo $email;

$query = "SELECT Name,InvestmentType FROM investor WHERE Email_I IN (SELECT Email_2 FROM follows WHERE Email_1 = '$email' AND Status =0)";

$result = mysqli_query ($conn,$query);
$response = array ();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)){

    array_push ($response,array("Name"=>$row[Name],"InvestmentType"=>$row[InvestmentType]));  
}


if(empty($response)){

    array_push ($response,array("Name"=>"no data","InvestmentType"=>"no data")); 

 }
echo json_encode ($response);
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't work means you did not get any answer? Please specify by [EDITING](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51536039/edit) your question (do not post a comment here). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Does your manifest have Internet permission ?